# Using radiant barrier inside my home to reduce heat coming through the skylight

Tags: skylight, radiant-barrier

How does the additional heat reflected back through the glass affect the integrity of the skylight glass?

Comment: How does the heat affect the _integrity_ of the glass? Are you concerned about the glass being damaged by the heat near the ceiling? Glass itself doesn't melt until at least 1400°C (2600°F). If your glass gets that hot, having it melt will be the last of your worries.

Answer (score 1):

Don't allow the sunlight to get to the glass - put a cover over the top either a film or a shading device.

Think about those who put the windscreens shields on cars in winter - on top of the windscreen but in summer they drape it over the dash, much better on the outside of the screen - don't let the heat into the interior at all...

Answer (score 0):

I vouch to make the heat dislike your skylight in the first place.

Attach a white towel using curtain rods as close to the window as possible.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your skylight. I have two large skylights ( 4' X 4' and 32" X 4') on a pitched roof . They are two layers of acrylic with about a two inch air gap. I do not notice heat coming in from them here in TX ( hot sun). If I get a ladder and go up into the area above the ceiling , it is hot but most heat stays up near the skylight above the ceiling level. They do not have a tint but may have some UV blocker. The infrared temperature of the 9' ceiling is 81 F, the drywall near the skylight is 97 F ( at 7pm ) , thermostat is 77.  F. So the heat just stay up near the skylight. I will measure again mid-day , I think it is going to be hot at the skylight.